# My PHP code returns Array to string conversion error on trying to display values of the radio buttons

Tags: php, radio-button

This is the PHP code to display some content and corresponding 5 radio buttons.

```
    <form name="functional"  method="post" action="funcsub.php">

    <?php
    $n=0;
    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','Sanjana','sanjana');
    mysqli_select_db($con,'mydatabase');

    $sql = mysqli_query($con,"select * from skills") or die("Failed");
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    ?>
    <br/>
    <?php
    echo $result["Technical"];
    echo "</br>";
    echo"<input type='radio' name='tech[$n]' value='0' required>0";

    echo"<input type='radio' name='tech[$n]' value='1'>1";         
    echo"<input type='radio' name='tech[$n]' value='2'>2";         
    echo"<input type='radio' name='tech[$n]' value='3'>3";          
    echo"<input type='radio' name='tech[$n]' value='4'>4";

    echo"<input type='radio' name='tech[$n]' value='5'>5";
    $n=$n+1;
    }  
    ?>   
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> 

    </html>
```

The below code is to get the values of the radio buttons and display it corresponding to the data.

```
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','Sanjana','sanjana');
    mysqli_select_db($con,'mydatabase');

    $sql = mysqli_query($con,"select * from skills") or die("Failed");
    while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
    {
    $skill = $result["Technical"];
    echo $skill;
    $op_num = $_POST['tech'];
    echo $op_num;
    echo "<br/>";

    }
    ?>
```

It returns an error stating Array to String Conversion. Any idea on how to resolve this??

Comment: `tech` is an array. Do `var_dump($op_num)` and you'll see what it contains.

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message?

Comment: Error: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp64\www\Lantrasoft\funcsub.php on line 11.

Comment: I should actually get the value of each group of radio buttons and store it in the database.